# In unity script, how to "rotate" and "rotate to" around pivot position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

in unity editor, when i enable "Pivot", gameobject will rotate around "pivot point" position, when i enable "Center", gameobject will rotate around "center point"

but if i use script to rotate, it always rotate around "center point", for ex, here is my scene:

[image]

I use following code:

```
    void Start()
    {
//        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0, 0, 90));
        transform.RotateAround(transform.position, new Vector3(0, 0, 1), 90);
    }
```

it rotate around "center point"

[image]

**if object has collider, i can get pivot point with colider.bounds, if not, how should i do?**

and even worse, in some case, i hope **rotate to** like set rotate in unity editor inspector, i use following code:

```
transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0, 0, 90))
```

I have no idea to adjust above code to rotate around pivot point

**update**

I think if i can "rotate", i can also impl "rotate to", so the key point is, how should i get "pivot point" that is used in RotateAround, to object has collider, I can get with colider.bounds with transform.position, to no collider object, how should i do?

Comment: Rotate around a pivot point is equivalent to:
1. translate object so that center of object is on pivot point (and remember the translation T relative to object space)
2. rotate object around center
3. translate back using T^-1 (relative to object space)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The pivot point is the-same as the `transform.position` you're already using. If you don't like where the pivot point is or the location the rotation is rotating against, you have two options:

**1**. Create new empty GameObject. Move it to the position you want your GameObject to rotate around. Once satisfied by that location, make this new GameObject a child of the GameObject you will be rotating around. Use the position of this new GameObject as the pivot rotation point for the `transform.RotateAround` function.

Drag the empty GameObject to the `customPivot` slot in the script below. That should give you a new pivot point to rotate your GameObject around.

```
public Transform customPivot;

void Update()
{
    transform.RotateAround(customPivot.position, Vector3.up, 20 * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

**2**. Open a 3D application and change the pivot point of your object, then save and re-import it into Unity.

Since this is just used to rotate object around, I suggest **#1**. If the problem is that the pivot point is not centered, I would suggest **#2**.